# Which event to catch for application shut down?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQueryMobile and phoneGap for a cross-device mobile application. I use html 5 local storage to persist records that worked on by user.

I don't know which phoneGap event to catch just before application shut-down so I can make sure data is saved before shutdown completes.

Base on suggestion from naughtur, I tried both unload and beforeunload events, neither of them got fired during app shutdown. Following is my code snip:

```
function persistTasks(){
    alert ("is unloading the app");
    offlineTasklist.set("tasks", tasklist); 
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("unload", persistTasks, false);
    login();
}

$(document).ready(init);
```

Comment: that's interesting. try unload and beforeunload events and post back whether they work. If not - we'll have to dig in phonegap apis

Comment: Thanks naugtur! I had accepted some of the answers, but the percentage does not seem to reflect them. But thanks anyway!!

Comment: Tried both unload and beforeunload, neither of them fired during application close.

Comment: I googled a bit and it looks like you will have to file a feature request for a new event in phonegap. Now only thing you can do is force user to click a save-alike button before exiting or call the function you want in intervals. In fact having seen it only saves one object I think you could run it every second or two...

Comment: Thanks naugtur! I filed http://phonegap.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20118-android/tickets/67-missing-event-for-application-shut-down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about using unload events, because those technically could (not sure if this happens in PhoneGap) also be fired when loading a different web page, i.e. going index.html to about.html inside your PhoneGap app.

At least for Android, you have access to [resume](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/blob/master/framework/assets/js/phonegap.js.base#L343) and [pause](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/blob/master/framework/assets/js/phonegap.js.base#L348) events. So you can do:

```
document.addEventListener('pause', function() { alert('this alert will show up in the background while your app is paused.'); }, false);
document.addEventListener('resume', function() { alert('this alert will show up when you open the app back up.'); }, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `unload` event is already avaliable in Android and Blackberry and will be implemented across all platforms soon.

See comments here:
http://phonegap.lighthouseapp.com/projects/20118-android/tickets/67-missing-event-for-application-shut-down