# catching a call to exit app

Tags: android, cordova

I have an Activity that extends phonegap, and in a js file there is a call to `navigator.app.exitApp` that ends the activity. I want to capture this call on my activity to present an exit dialog.
I'm not familier with PhoneGap and JS.

How can i catch the call to exitApp?

Thank You.

Comment: Having an "exit dialog" is an exceptionally bad idea. After all, that dialog will rarely be shown -- if the user presses HOME, your process may be terminated some time later, without your "exit dialog". Please come up with a UI that does the right thing automatically, rather than expecting users to do something in an "exit dialog".

Comment: The purpose is to ask the user if he's sure he wants to exit when pressing 'back'. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Because you are not valuing your users' time. If they accidentally press BACK and leave your app, they can always re-launch it. This happens rather infrequently.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, its sounds right,
But the client wants this and its written in the spec so I'm implementing it.

Comment: Since I am unconvinced that what you want is even possible, I doubt that you will be implementing it. IMHO, you will be better served going back to your client, pointing out that this proposed "exit dialog" violates [recommended UI design patterns](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html). Also see http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/exit-application-dialogs-are-evil-dont.html

Comment: @CommonsWare is correct. Your app may terminate on it's on later on anyway. I've had to add a back button override for some small projects I've worked on to tell the user "Hey don't do this, or the current thing you're doing will stop", but then again you can just ran that task in the background. READ the three points the author makes in the link above about the Flickr app.

Comment: I will try to convince the client, but you know how it is with clients.
At the moment I'll just try to implement this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave Up on trying. Decided to write a plugin that calls a method to exit, removed calls from js to `navigator.app.exitApp`. Not sure if this qualifies as own answer, but this is my solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend not implementing an exit dialog given @CommonsWare comments. But if you can't convince your client to change this request, here are a couple links that may help.

[Which event to catch for application shut down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677507/which-event-to-catch-for-application-shut-down)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Essentially you'll have a listener for the pause, unload, or backbutton event(s). Which one(s) to use will probably depend a bit on how this on exit feature fits into everything else.

Comment: I think its the opposite of what I looked for.
I'm looking to catch event sent by Phongap an this seems to be Phongap catching events, am I wrong?